# `sudo apt-get update` returns connection errors with some repositories, and can't update

Tags: command-line, apt, updates, sudo

as i remember, after i uninstall some packages with ros with `sudo apt-get autoremove <name package>` i can't get `sudo apt-get update` anymore, this is the result after i text it on my terminal :

```
Err http://packages.ros.org trusty InRelease                                   

Err http://packages.ros.org trusty Release.gpg         
  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/InRelease  

W: Failed to fetch http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release.gpg  Unable to connect to packages.ros.org:http:

W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

after i text this `find /etc/apt -name '*.list' -exec bash -c 'echo -e "\n$1\n"; cat -n "$1"' _ '{}' \;`
 the result is :

/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list

```
 deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu trusty main
```

/etc/apt/sources.list

```
 deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-security main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
 deb http://kambing.ui.ac.id/ubuntu/ trusty-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
```

what should i do? i have to install some package, and the system does not permit me to do so...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository at fault is the `packages.ros.org` one, with an "Unable to Connect" error.  This in turn points to `ftp.osuosl.org` from the DNS lookups I just ran.  It also is 'working' from what I can tell.

It's possible your system is not able to reach those servers, either because there's network filtering somewhere along the lines that're blocking the access, or there's intermittent network issues, or your ISP is blocking access.  If all other repositories are working, then you'll have to debug connectivity between you and that repository server.

It looks to me though like that's the only repository giving you issues.  If the issues do not resolve then you will need to try and reach out to those who maintain the repository (sorry, I don't know who they are), and try and resolve the issues there.  There's not much we can really do from here, though.